# Como eliminar pequeño margen en TOP al añadir Position: Fixed en menu lateral

Tags: html5, css3, menú, css-grid-layout, margin

Estoy haciendo un layout para una intranet. En la que estoy haciendo un menú lateral, el problema, que al añadirle el position fixed, se añade un pequeño margen arriba de la web:

Este es mi CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Average Sans;
    background-color: #F2F3F4;
}

.menu {
    min-height: 800px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 260px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.contenido {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 270px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Los DIV, del html, son dos simples DIV, primero el menu y despúes el de contenido. con loren ipsum.

Añado una imagen con el pequeño márgen que se crea:

[image: Menu lateral problema al añadir fixed en el CSS]

¿Como podría eliminar este margen?, o si se les ocurre otra opción de estructurar el menú, también agradeceré la ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya probaste html,body{height:100%;width:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;} en tu CSS?

Comment: Si, y no me ha funcionado, acabo de decantarme por la propiedad wrap de CSS, lo que me ha facilitado mucho las cosas, voy a hacer una respuesta por si a alguien le pudiera servir también

Comment: Genial me incluyo de curioso :)

Comment: con ese código no sale ningún margen

Answer (score 1):

He preferido solucionar esto, con la propiedad Wrap de CSS3, de la siguiente forma:

```
.row {  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu {
    min-height: 800px;
    background-color: white;
    flex: 22%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.contenido {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 78%;
}
```

Dentro de un `div` llamado ROW, he añadido primero el `div` menu, y después el de contenido.

El css del `body`, se queda igual.